# Showing linear functionals are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

In general: 
Given $f_1,f_2,...,f_n\in W^*$. To show they are linearly independent, will it be enough to take the standart base of $W$,$B=\{e_1,...,e_n\}$ and its dual base $B^*=\{g_1,g_2,...,g_n\}$ and show that $[f_i]_{B^*}$ ($f_i$ vector coordinate according to $B^*$) is linearly independent?

Comment: Yes...but that looks a little messy, doesn't it?

Comment: I guess it depends on the linear functionals you are given. Generally speaking, is there another "algorithm" to do that?

Comment: Without anything else (say, some inner product and/or Riesz theorem or stuff), I guess you could directly go by the definition: assume there are scalars $\;a_i\;$ s.t. $\;\sum a_i f_i=0\implies \sum a_if_i(w)=0\;,\;\;\forall\,w\in W\;$ and etc.

Comment: Again, under some circumstances going for the definition can be better. Thank you!